# Is it ok to use "NOW" - instead of "JUST"- in a simple past tense sentence?

Tags: grammar, meaning

Somebody is cleaning and dusting away with a feathery thing in his hand. When he finished cleaning a table where people were sitting at, he said:

**I finished here now.**

The use of **"now"** in simple past sentence caught my attention.

Since the finishing has just taken place, shouldn't he have said:

**I just finished here.**

Comment: Well, I would have said "I've finished here now", but this gets us into the old argument about American vs British use of the perfect tense.

Comment: @KateBunting - looks like "I finished here" is pretty rare in all forms of standard English, according to [googlengram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+finished+here%2C+I%27ve+finished+here&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) - even the examples I could find referenced are constructions such as "After/once I finished here, I did something else".  I would say the OPs sentence is not idiomatic, but yeah it certainly wouldn't be used by native speakers in the UK.

Comment: I also note that "I finished here now" could be a mishearing of "I've finished here now".  The contracted "have" is very subtle, and some learners might not be able to hear it or distinguish it, and if the OP is using subtitles, they just might be wrong.

Comment: @BillyKerr, yes that might be the case. I now understand that "I have finished here now" is a correct sentence. But then does it mean the same as "I have just finished here"? or Are they different in meaning? When do you say "I have finished here now" and when do you say "I have just finished here"?

Comment: @Yunus do you think you might have misheard it?  Do you have a sound sample we can listen to?  Did you see it written in the subtitles?  In standard English we tend to use the past perfect in situations where something has just happened. Now, that's not to say it is always used. Some native speakers have dialects/accents, and some might just not pronounce their words clearly, especially in informal/spoken/colloquial English. It might not be your fault that you couldn't hear it.

Comment: @Yunus "I have just finished here" and "I have finished here now" are pretty similar. And in this context either could be used.  The use of the present perfect tells us it "just happened".    You could leave out the just/now, and it would still mean the same.